# Merging the StreetView Control (Pegman) and Zoom Control in Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to configure the Google Maps JavaScript API (v3) such that the StreetView (pegman) and Zoom Controls are touching, just like maps.google.com? I believe I have tried all of the configuration options and can't get them to touch.